# Process Paypal IPN in Django view

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-ipn

According to the [PayPal IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/) documentation, you have to respond to an IPN by first sending an empty HTTP 200 response to `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr` and then send an HTTP POST request.  The only way I could figure out to send an HTTP 200 response was by returning `HttpResponse('')` in the view, which works since the IPN simulator says the "IPN was sent and the handshake was verified."  But then how would I send the HTTP POST request when the view has already returned?  My plan was to use urllib2 to generate the POST request.

I also would like to send an HTTP 200 response without using `HttpResponse('')` since I don't know where the original request is coming from, and I want to be sure that I'm sending the response to `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`.  I've looked at urllib2, requests, and PyCurl, and I've been unable to find a way to create an empty response to a particular URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `requests` or `urllib2` to make a POST request to verify the IPN *before* you return the `HttpResponse('')`; the docs imply you have to do it in the opposite order, but you don't actually have to, and this way is a lot simpler in most web frameworks.  So your view should look vaguely like

```
def ipn(request):
    verification = requests.POST(PAYPAL_URL, data=request.body)
    if verification.text == 'VERIFIED':
        # process IPN
        return HttpResponse('')
    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Note that if this errors somewhere, you will return a 500 to PayPal, and they will retry.  If you do this too much, they will get annoyed at you and eventually deactivate your account, so make sure you are getting alerted of the error in some fashion.  (You could also wrap things in a `try`/`except` block, but then you risk returning a 200 without actually doing your processing if there's an error, which may be worse.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out.  It'd be good if someone from PayPal can confirm.  I've been bending over backwards trying to do the request after the response.  Last night I found out about Django signals.  request_finished is what I need, but I was trying to figure out how to trigger the signal only for the IPN request.

Answer (score 0):

just respond to the request made by paypal. for the other requests no response (403 http status)

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

def answer_to_pp_ipn():
    # ...
    if 'paypal' in request.META['HTTP_HOST']:
        return HttpResponse('OK 200')

    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

and as you mentioned, `requests` is the perfect choice to [make a post request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/).

Comment: This is certainly not secure; anyone can hit your endpoint with any host/user-agent/payload they want.  The only way to confirm that it's legitimate is to POST it back to Paypal.